# Is SSL the only way to go for the exchange of information from a remote to a webserver?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, security, unity-game-engine

I am part of an indie game developer team and we are working on a project in Unity (C#).
I used Drupal on the backend (PHP/MySQL) and I want to retrieve data from the database to our software.

So for example if I want the user to log in via Drupal's authenticate (server sided hashing of sent passwords), the user needs to submit his username and password via unity WWWForm or c# HttpRequest at first (client).

If I've done my research properly, there are three possibilites to send data securely (please correct me if I'm wrong):

1. Implement own password encryption/decryption (use Drupal's password hashing after server side decryption)
2. Implement drupal's hashing method(s) in c# (client)
3. Buy SSL certificate and go with HTTPS

It's possible to sniff the HTTP connection or decompile the software, right? Do possibility 1) and 2) make any sense then? Would one of the two methods be secure enough?

Is SSL the only way for us to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how secure you want things, and how far you believe an attacker would go to intercept a password. For example, if you use client-side password hashing via JavaScript, it is theoretically possible for the JavaScript library to be intercepted as it travels to the user, and modified so that it sends a plaintext copy of the password. This can then be intercepted as it is sent to your server. But, since you are working on a computer game, this may not be very likely to happen.

SSL with a genuine certificate would go some way to preventing this, since it is theoretically impossible for a MITM (man in the middle) attack to sniff, never mind modify, data as it travels down the wire. To do that, they would need to have a copy of your private server key, either by stealing it from your server or stealing/obtaining it from the certificate authority. While this is not impossible, it is most unlikely to happen.

SSL certificates of the lowest security are now very inexpensive, and in general will save you a lot of work thinking about how to implement security. I'd just go with this option.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Implement own password encryption/decryption (use Drupal's password
>      hashing after server side decryption)
> 2. Implement drupal's hashing
>      method(s) in c# (client)

The problem with these methods is that the client side hashed version effectively becomes the password. So if a MITM grabs the hashed version, they can simply replay it to log in.

> 3. Buy SSL certificate and go with HTTPS

Definitely. As well as encryption, HTTPS provides assurance that the client is talking to your server and this hasn't been MITM'd and it will also protect against replay attacks (an attacker recreating the login request from their own connection and then acting on the response).

Comment: we decided to go with startcom's free certificate.

Comment: "So if a MITM grabs the hashed version" - that's a very good point, though I suppose it could be mitigated by using a random number generated on the client and using this in the hash also. The server would have to reject any attempts to use this token twice.

Comment: @halfer: That would protect against that particular attack, however a MITM could potentially intercept the initial request, drop it, and then replay it themselves without the original request having made it to the server. Therefore it won't have expired and they could log in. This depends on _how_ the connection is being MITM'd. HTTPS inherently protects against this.

Comment: Mm, interesting. I guess it could be combined with a timestamp hash or maybe an expiring token from the server to the client. As per my answer, I entirely agree that SSL is the way to go - but it is interesting to ponder upon what can be done without it.

Comment: @halfer: The main issue with non SSL solutions is that they run at application layer (OSI model). They can easily be intercepted, modified, blocked, etc, without the server being aware. HTTPS runs on TLS which means all the attacker sees is encrypted data and [can't then intercept it and replay it from their own connection](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/20105/8340) due to TCP sequence numbers being accouted for in the MAC, and each `Client Hello` message would cause a different random server value for the master secret.